# Dragable forms and save the data to json file

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

i want to make this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-survey-creation-golkhg be dragable and save to json file, so i can make a view for the data, i've use angular cdk but i'm stuck in this function

```
onDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.items, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }
```

i can't find a variable to replace `this.items` , can someone help me? and of course i want to store the data to json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so, you have to upgrade your cdk version to 7.3.7 as this functionality was released in that version.

After that in your question **this.items** needs to be replaced by

```
this.surveyForm.get('surveyQuestions')['controls']
```

Then this function will look like as below:

```
onDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.surveyForm.get('surveyQuestions')['controls'], event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
}
```

Comment: i currently use that version, and thanks for the answer, but how to make it animated like this https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview ?

Comment: and in my json, it doesn't change the order

Comment: No it will not change any order in your json. If you want main display in json too. You need to add display_order property in your questions.

Comment: how exactly to do that? someone told me about this too https://alligator.io/angular/change-detection-strategy/

Comment: Can you update this stackblitz with angular 7? I will update this code

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-38vdnx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: heres a simple version

Comment: see this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iranzm?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: thanks it works, but can you look at my code again? there's a commented code it's just embeden video i want to add it to the array, do you know how?

Comment: You have this video card with each question or different formarray?

Comment: just like google forms actually, user can add videos to as many as they want, or maybe you have better approach for this

Comment: after i copied your code this appear ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined when i drag the card

Comment: You need to create another formarray like questions

Comment: Have you added 'display_order' in your question form?

Comment: form array? so i exclude the video card from stepQuestions formArray?

Comment: Sorry, it will be part of that question but as formarray

Comment: inside stepQuestion but i create new formarray inside?

Comment: yes like questions:new FormArray{new FormGroup{videos:new FormArray{new FormGroup}}} As you have created for questions

Comment: sadly i can't make it, i can give you a repo though, i can't add a dialog module from nebular

Comment: You can share the repo

Comment: https://github.com/naonvl/kewirus-test/tree/dev here's the repo, the code is on pages/admin/user-projects/step-list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211531/discussion-between-gourav-garg-and-naoval).